# jQuery automatically add +1 to the radio button name when the div containing the radio button is cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div named `#step-content` that I am cloning when the `#btn-addProduct` is clicked. This div contains radio buttons which gets cloned too.

My problem is when the radio button gets cloned now instead of two radio buttons we have four with the same `name="packaging"`. This only allows me to select 1 out of 4.

What I want is that when the `#step-content` is cloned the cloned radio buttons should have `a +1` added to its name which will make `name="packaging"` into `name="packaging1"`.

My existing code is:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-step form-step1">
  <p class="step-number">1</p>
  <div id="step-content" class="step-content">

      <select name="product-type" form="cost-form">
        <option value="product" selected disabled>Product Type</option>
        <option value="product1">Product Type 1</option>
        <option value="product2">Product Type 2</option>
        <option value="product3">Product Type 3</option>
        <option value="product4">Product Type 4</option>
        <option value="product5">Product Type 5</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length" />
      <span class="x">X</span>
      <input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width" />
      <span class="x">X</span>
      <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height" />
      <input class="weight" type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Weight" />

      <div class="packaging">
        <label for="packaging">Needs Packaging?</label>
        <input type="radio" name="packaging" value="yes" checked /> yes
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="packaging" value="no" /> no
      </div>

      <input type="text" class="qty" name="qty" placeholder="QTY" />

  </div>
</div>
<!-- end form-step -->

<div class="add-product">
  <a id="btn-addProduct"><img src="img/add-product.png" alt="Add Another Product" /></a> <span>Add Another Product</span>
</div>
```

The jQuery that I am using to clone the div is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('btn-addProduct').onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('step-content');

function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
  clone.id = "step-content" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

JSFIDDLE link: 
https://jsfiddle.net/qdryvgw7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
  clone.id = "step-content" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  //this will change name of the radio buttons under newly created step-content
  $("#step-content"+ i + " input:radio").attr("name", "packaging"+ i);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vjxm6uq/)

Answer (score 1):

Please check I've added one more line which is changing the name of the packaging radio button.

```js
document.getElementById('btn-addProduct').onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('step-content');

function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
  clone.id = "step-content" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
  
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  $("#" + clone.id).find(".packaging input").each(function() { this.name = this.name + i });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-step form-step1">
  <p class="step-number">1</p>
  <div id="step-content" class="step-content">
    <p>
      <select name="product-type" form="cost-form">
        <option value="product" selected disabled>Product Type</option>
        <option value="product1">Product Type 1</option>
        <option value="product2">Product Type 2</option>
        <option value="product3">Product Type 3</option>
        <option value="product4">Product Type 4</option>
        <option value="product5">Product Type 5</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length" />
      <span class="x">X</span>
      <input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width" />
      <span class="x">X</span>
      <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height" />
      <input class="weight" type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Weight" />

      <div class="packaging">
        <label for="packaging">Needs Packaging?</label>
        <input type="radio" name="packaging" value="yes" checked /> yes
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="packaging" value="no" /> no
      </div>

      <input type="text" class="qty" name="qty" placeholder="QTY" />
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end form-step -->

<div class="add-product">
  <a id="btn-addProduct"><img src="img/add-product.png" alt="Add Another Product" /></a> <span>Add Another Product</span>
</div>
```